# Scroll magic not working. Not sure if even the library was loaded

Tags: javascript, html

sorry for the unformattedness of the question.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.7/ScrollMagic.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.7/plugins/debug.addIndicators.min.js"></script>
<script src="/views/app.js"> </script>
```

this is on my index.ejs file on the body section.
And for my app.js file,

```
// JavaScript source code
function splitScroll() {
    const controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();

    new ScrollMagic.Scene({
        duration: '100%',
        triggerElement = '.about-title',
        triggerHook: 0
    })
        .addIndicators()
        .addTo(controller);
}

splitScroll();
```

And I can't quite even figure out if the library of scrollmagic was even loaded or not.

First, How could I check if any of these three libaries are loaded/working?

I intentionally tried adding

```
if (true) {
    window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com/';
```

on app.js file, and nothing happened. Does this mean that app.js has not been loaded?
I mean if i ctrl + U on the page, and click the 3 above mentioned links, it seems like it's working fine.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console? `triggerElement = ...` should be `triggerElement: ...`.

Comment: thank you so much! you saved my life, I was putting 3 hours on this silly mistake.